# p:contextMenu does not work in FireFox

Tags: primefaces

I'm using the contextMenu component of the primefaces framework.
With Firefox, contextMenu is not displayed. This is the classic menu that appears.
Can you help me ?

Here my code :

```
<p:contextMenu>
   <p:menuitem value="Ajouter une note" 
               actionListener="#{noteManagerBean.nouvelleNote()}" 
               oncomplete="PF('widgetNoteDialog').show()" 
               update="idNoteDialog"/>
</p:contextMenu>
```

Comment: It is working in the showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/contextmenu/basic.xhtml Check: Primefaces version. JSF impl/version. Firefox caches. Firefox version.

Comment: Firefox plugins, security settings etc

Comment: And **ALWAYS** create a [mcve]

Comment: Primefaces 6.1.2   JSF 2.2   Firefox 61.0